# WKT for a doughnut shaped world projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text

I understand next to nothing when I look at a WKT string, but I've copy-pasted and used a few of them for work. However, I came to think of the doughnut shaped world in which my friends and I play Dungeons and Dragons and was wondering if I would be able to build a mapping software that projects that world.

Preferably I'd like to project the world in a Mercator like way, so it's okay for things further north and south to look bigger, as long as the proportions are maintained.

The map would go +/-180° longitude and +/-180° latitude instead of the normal +/-90° latitude. I'd also like the 0° latitude to go along the outside equator and the +/-180° latitude to go along the inside equator.

The circumference of the outer equator is 20 000 km and the circumference of the inner equator is 6 666 km. The circumference along the latitude is also 6 666 km.

The surface areas on the inside of the doughnut are relatively unimportant as travel is extremely restricted by massive mountain chains and thus unexplored. The map would probably mostly say "here be dragons" or something in that area.

My question is threefold (feel free to only answer the parts which you feel reasonably certain about):

- Is it possible to write a WKT for such a projection?
- Can Proj4, or whichever library handles projections in GDAL and Sharpmap, handle such a WKT?
- Idon'tunderstandWKT,couldsomeonewriteitformeprettyplease? >.<

Answer (score 1):

If you change your world coordinates to match Earth's lat-long (ie halve the actual doughnut "latitude" to get latitude from -90 -> +90) then you can use any projection that works with lat-long.

Note that Mercator projections will put your inner mountains at the top *and* the bottom, and a player crossing the Dunshire Pass across the range from the top will appear at the bottom.

The properties of projections on the sphere (such as preserving distance, direction, or area) won't be valid when projecting a doughnut.

You might also find https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ useful.